PushNotifications: Upgrade to FCMv1 is not delivering Templated Notifications from Azure
Using this link GCM/FCM notifications to FCM v1. I am trying to migrate from GCM/FCM notifications to FCM v1.
From the guide, I

Configured the Firebase Service Account Credentials in Azure Notification Hub.
Updated backend SDK C# code use FCM v1 platform during installation & registration of push notification.
Verified that the device is actually registered in notification hub (by getting registrations from notification hub).
Checked that Installation is now having the new Platform : FcmV1 instead of Gcm
Verified that notification is delivered to app when sent from firebase console.

The problem is:

I am able to call SendFcmNativeNotificationAsync() and send a notification to the registered device.
This is my template according to the migration documentation. "{ "message" : { "notification" : { "body" : "$(message)", "title" : "Test" }}}" and my call to templated notification is $NotificationOutcome = $client.SendTemplateNotificationAsync( $templateParameterDictionary, '$InstallationId:{61D21000-XXXX-}').Result
But I am not able to call SendTemplateNotificationAsync() and send a notification to the registered device.
When sending notification from "Test Send" in Azure Portal, it does not get delivered.
When sending template notification from code (C# - Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs nuget), it shows same error.


This was a bug by Microsoft in the code and has been fixed.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1658068/pushnotifications-upgrade-to-fcmv1-is-not-deliveri?comment=answer-1518818&page=1
